# Ganglia fails to communicate with Apache HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, monitoring, ganglia

I installed Ganglia to monitor the HBase cluster. I'm using `ganglia-3.3.0`.

- Hadoop version: `hadoop-1.1.2`
- HBase version : `hbase-0.94.8`

My Hadoop cluster comprises of 1 master node and 2 slave nodes.

Ganglia gmetad_server is configured on the master node

I changed the `hbase/conf/hadoop-metrics.properties` file.

```
hbase.class=org.apache.hadoop.metrics.ganglia.GangliaContext31
hbase.period=10  
hbase.servers=hostname_of_ganglia_server:8649
```

I started the service `gmond` on the master as well as slaves.

I get the basic metrics from the cluster (cpu, disk, load, ...)

But I'm not getting any HBase metrics from the Cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was with the `gmond.conf` file. When I commented the following values, I got the HBase metrics in Ganglia.

```
mcast_join = 239.2.11.71
bind = 239.2.11.71
```